# Partial nested selection in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a set of data (i.e an array). A subset of this set, i.e some of elements, is selected, e.g. put into another array.
I use '**selectAll data enter exit**' approach of d3.js to manipulate the set of data. But I can't figure out how use the same approach for the subset. An instance:

```
var set = [2, 5, 10];
var subset = [2];
```

Lets say I have a group for each element of the set and a circle. And I need a text in the same group if this element is in the subset. Correspondent SVG elements which I'd like to have:

```
<g>
<circle></circle>
<text></text>
</g>
<g>
<circle></circle>
</g>
<g>
<circle></circle>
</g>
```

I've made an example http://jsfiddle.net/5af44ryg/ where one can see how it works. Yes, it works, but the implementation of dynamic selection is quite ugly. I can't figure out how to use 'selectAll data enter exit' approach in this case.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. The D3 approach would be to use nested data, see http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

Comment: @lars-kotthoff That example uses nested selections while having child data defined for each parent. It's ok for tables. Lets get abstract from tables... Assume we have <td>5</td> element missing Iby design) for the table given in this example. How would be a correct SVG code generated in this case?

Comment: Well the outer nesting would be the `g` elements and then you would add `circle` and `text` depending on the data as you say. You would still need to check this manually -- I guess my main point is that you could change the data format or preprocess the data to make this easier for you.

Comment: @lars-kotthoff. Yes, I do it manually as I've shown [in the example](http://jsfiddle.net/5af44ryg/). I spent a lot of time trying to apply the 'standard' approach for this problem on my way of learning d3.js. However, it seems impossible. That's why I've asked the community.

Comment: Well your example is what's confusing me -- it doesn't have the same structure as the SVG you've posted here and dynamic behaviour which you don't mention. As I've said, it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.